# Acer aspire ES1-521 : Cannot turn on wifi after switch to linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, hardware-failure

I recently switched to linux (mint 18 KDE) after the windows install on my became corrupted (read: I cannot go back into windows to fix this issue). The wifi refuses to work, `sudo rfkill list` confirming that `phy0: Wireless LAN` is `Hard blocked: yes`. My computer has a wifi key, `fn-f3`, but this does nothing.

is there another way to enable the wifi card? on windows I had no issues (until the whole thing failed).

the laptop is an Acer Aspire ES1-521 (i don't know if they make other versions, but it uses an AMD A8)

I have no wired connection where I am, so I cannot connect the laptop to the internet to fix issue. I have another computer that I can download stuff to and transfer via USB.

I am moderately familiar with computers in general, and linux.

Comment: Which wifi hardware is it using? Enter `lspci` or `lsusb` from a terminal window to see which PCI resp. USB hardware you have. What do the logs say directly after boot, when it tries to load the drivers? Logs are usually in `/var/log/syslog`, so do `less /var/log/syslog` as root, or `sudo less /var/log/syslog` to read it. Look for anything that is about your particular wifi card.

Comment: Can you unblock the card using `rfkill`, e.g. `sudo rfkill unblock wlan`, and after that `sudo rfkill list` shows it's not blocked anymore?

Comment: @dirkt `sudo rfkill unblock wlan` removed the soft block, but not the hard block

Comment: Then it's some kind of driver problem, either for the wifi card, or for the hardware that blocks wireless. Especially the latter is always "fun" to debug, even for experienced Linux users, because each laptop is different, and while Windows is supported with special drivers etc., Linux isn't ... Definitely look at the logs, put them up somewhere (pastebin, ...) and post a link if you can't make sense of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

to my `etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Then a quick reboot and everything was up and running!

Comment: Can you explain why this works and/or how you arrived at this solution?  It isn't obvious from the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 arrived at this solution from response #7 in [this forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181194) that I found while researching my problem. I guessed that if `blacklist wmi` didnt work maybe `blacklist acer-wmi` would since I have an acer PC

Comment: That's... an INCREDIBLY lucky guess. Are you sure you just guessed it?

Comment: @adam I also tried `acer_wmi` `acer wmi`, and `atheros-wmi` (my wifi card is an atheros one) but `acer-wmi` worked so I left it

Comment: did not work for me :(

Answer (score -1):

OK!  l Also have this same notebook laptop..... .....same problem I fixed it 100 % working wifi....

STAP 1: DOWNLODE THIS ZIP https://www.atheros-drivers.com/download-driver-nr-301-for-atheros-AR5BWB222-and-Windows8.html

STAP 2: extract zip file in specific location.

STAP 3:
1.Open the "Run" dialog box by pressing and holding the Windows key, then press the R key ("Run").
2.Type devmgmt.msc

STAP 4: locate " OTHER DEVICES > network controller > right click > update driver software > browse my computer for driver software > browse the specified folder location that you extracted your zip file (include subfolders) > NEXT.....

Comment: You should correct the numerous spelling and formatting problems in this answer.  If you as the author do that I will reverse my downvote. (i.e. STAP vs Step).